# Combing abundance data table and a metadata table in R

Tags: r

I am working with two tab-separated tables in R:

**Table 1**: Species (rows) count data for multiple samples (columns)

```
SpeciesID   16Snem1 nem2    16Snem3 16Snem4
K00368  452.0   0.0 470.0   0.0
K00376  469.5   15.0    332.0   0.0
K00387  401.5   10.0    302.0   0.0
```

**Table 2**: Metadata associated with each sample

```
SampleID    OceanRegion Habitat Depth
16Snem1 GulfofMexico    Seep    1000
16Snem2 GulfofMexico    Shore   1425
16Snem3 SouthernCalifornia  LopheliaSite    400
16Snem4 SouthernCalifornia  LopheliaSite    495
```

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to `merge` or `bind` these two tables in R?
2. Once combined, how can I plot the count data based on metadata like the OceanRegion, Habitat, and Depth instead of plot each sample?

Comment: At a conceptual level, I think you want to make the `count` data into a long-format ("tidy" data) with three columns - `SpeciesID`, `SampleID`, and `value` (or similar names). Then you will have a column that you can use to merge the `metadata` `SampleID` column back against.

Answer (score 1):

A data.table apprach:

first melt your first table to long format, and then perform a left join on table 2.

```
library( data.table )
melt( dt1, id.vars = "SpeciesID", 
      measure.vars = patterns( "^16Snem" ), 
      variable.name = "SampleID" )[ dt2, `:=`( OceanRegion = i.OceanRegion,
                                               Habitat = i.Habitat, 
                                               Depth = i.Depth),
                                    on = "SampleID"][]

#     SpeciesID SampleID value        OceanRegion      Habitat Depth
#  1:    K00368  16Snem1 452.0       GulfofMexico         Seep  1000
#  2:    K00376  16Snem1 469.5       GulfofMexico         Seep  1000
#  3:    K00387  16Snem1 401.5       GulfofMexico         Seep  1000
#  4:    K00368  16Snem2   0.0       GulfofMexico        Shore  1425
#  5:    K00376  16Snem2  15.0       GulfofMexico        Shore  1425
#  6:    K00387  16Snem2  10.0       GulfofMexico        Shore  1425
#  7:    K00368  16Snem3 470.0 SouthernCalifornia LopheliaSite   400
#  8:    K00376  16Snem3 332.0 SouthernCalifornia LopheliaSite   400
#  9:    K00387  16Snem3 302.0 SouthernCalifornia LopheliaSite   400
# 10:    K00368  16Snem4   0.0 SouthernCalifornia LopheliaSite   495
# 11:    K00376  16Snem4   0.0 SouthernCalifornia LopheliaSite   495
# 12:    K00387  16Snem4   0.0 SouthernCalifornia LopheliaSite   495
```

No plotting should be easy..

**sample data used**

```
library( data.table )

dt1 <- fread("SpeciesID   16Snem1 16Snem2    16Snem3 16Snem4
K00368  452.0   0.0 470.0   0.0
K00376  469.5   15.0    332.0   0.0
K00387  401.5   10.0    302.0   0.0")

dt2 <- fread("SampleID    OceanRegion Habitat Depth
16Snem1 GulfofMexico    Seep    1000
16Snem2 GulfofMexico    Shore   1425
16Snem3 SouthernCalifornia  LopheliaSite    400
16Snem4 SouthernCalifornia  LopheliaSite    495")
```